# I get a different form resolution from what I see in the designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

i'm using a lenovo y50 laptop with windows 8.1
I have a problem in visual studio 2013, that I create a form in the designer, when I compile and run the program I see all the controls differently.

here's an example

[image]

thank you

Comment: check your Display Options in control panel and make sure you size of all items is not changed, also could be something to do with your theme setting. Try to reset that to default.

Comment: everything look at the default..
http://pasteboard.co/2PwnnTH3.png

Comment: Make sure you have `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` in your Main() method.

Comment: thanks man! is there a way to do that permanently?

Answer (score 1):

The visual studio designer will not display the forms from the Windows theme. It will use a default display.

Once you run the program, the API will pull from the windows theme and use that to display your windows.

Here is an example in Windows 7 that does the same thing:

[image]

Comment: all the windows look like in the form. i uploaded a screen shot of the display options window